# How to make process start when running in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, process

When I add the site to run in IIS, my process.start() does not work to open the process. It only runs locally. Is there a way to make that method also work in IIS?

Comment: You can only start a program on the server, not on the client.

Comment: How to do this ? How to run my exe when using the server ?

Comment: You can show a popup on the website that the user has to start the program on their local computer.